# Text editing with column markers

Tags: text-editors

I need to be able to set **multiple column numbers** (as opposed to a single end-of-the-line marker) in a text editor.  Is there a way to do this in a commonly-available editor?

Crimson Editor has such feature but the number of markers is limited to only two:

[image: column markers in Crimson Editor]

UltraEdit and EditPlus support them too, but they're not free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as always: [vim](http://www.vim.org) (free, works everywhere, is everywhere)

[image]

you can set the markers via `:set cc=10,20,30,40`. see the [colorcolumn option](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27colorcolumn%27).